# Who can i Use de arg of a function to call a dataframe

Tags: r

I create a statistics descriptive function

```
descr_u<-function(x){a<-data.frame(round(rbind( Minimo=min(x,na.rm=TRUE),
                Maximo=max(x,na.rm=TRUE),
                Media=mean(x,na.rm=TRUE),2))
retunr(a)}

descr(iris[,1])
```

I would like that the return have the same name of colnames ("Sepal.Length")

Comment: I edited my answer to explain you what it is not possible to get the colnames in your current function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, you are applying this function for a single column of a dataframe. You will like that this function to be assign with the name of the column on which you are applying the function.

However, as you are doing it, you are passing a vector of a single dimension in your function, so your function can't find a colname to recycle for the assignment of the object `a`.

Indeed, when you are writing `iris[,1]`, R tend to convert this single column to a single dimension vector and so your object `x` does not have two dimensions and neither a `name`. You can verify it by entering:

```r
> head(iris[,1])
[1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4
```

You can see that no colname are return.

So, to circumwent this problem, you have to create a function requiring two arguments. You can do it in two ways:

***1) Function with values and the character vector to be used as colnames:***

```r
descr<-function(x, name){
  a<-round(rbind(Minimo = min(x,na.rm=TRUE),
                 Maximo = max(x,na.rm=TRUE),
                 Media = mean(x,na.rm=TRUE),
                 Mediana = median(x,na.rm=TRUE),
                 Rango = max(x[!is.na(x)])-min(x[!is.na(x)])))
  colnames(a) <- name
  assign(name,a,.GlobalEnv)
  return(a)
}
```

You will use it like that:

```r
> descr2(iris[,1],colnames(iris)[1])
        Sepal.Length
Minimo             4
Maximo             8
Media              6
Mediana            6
Rango              4
```

***2) Passing the name of the dataframe and the column number***

```r
descr<-function(x, indicator){
  y <- x[,indicator]
  a <-round(rbind(Minimo = min(y,na.rm=TRUE),
                 Maximo = max(y,na.rm=TRUE),
                 Media = mean(y,na.rm=TRUE),
                 Mediana = median(y,na.rm=TRUE),
                 Rango = max(y[!is.na(y)])-min(y[!is.na(y)])))
  colnames(a) <- colnames(x)[indicator]
  assign(colnames(x)[indicator],a,.GlobalEnv)
  return(a)
}
```

You can test it (and noticed the new object "Sepal.Width" in your environment:

```r
> descr(iris,2)
        Sepal.Width
Minimo            2
Maximo            4
Media             3
Mediana           3
Rango             2
```

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: I made a mistake, the function is for only one column, without "apply". I would like to know how modify the function to get "Sepal.Lenght" in column`name without specify

Comment: @CarlosJara, no you can't (or at least I don't know) because when you are passing the argument `iris[,1]` into your function, you are passing a vector without colnames, so your function can't find from which dataframe it is coming from. The solution is to passed two arguments in your function, either as I presented you in a first place or by entering the name of the dataframe and the indicator of the column. I will edit my answer to show you how to do that.